# Выбор из таблицы на основе другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица 1

```
id | val
--------
1  | 100
--------
2  | 101
--------
3  | 100
--------
4  | 105
```

и таблица 2

```
id | mainid | val
-----------------
1  |   1    | 10
-----------------
2  |   2    | 11
-----------------
3  |   4    | 10
```

Нужно выбрать из таблицы 1 записи, которых нет в таблице 2, где mainid это id записи из первой таблицы. Здесь результатом будет id 3, так как во второй таблице нет строки с mainid 3. Как составить запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT mainid FROM table2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для выполнения операции вычитания рекомендую воспользоваться left join и фильтрацией по присоединяемому полю:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.mainin where t1.id is null
```